# Pegar itens do carrinho de compras com PHP

Tags: php

Tenho esse código que faz uma compra transparente do Pagseguro.

```
$params = array(
            'email'                     => $PAGSEGURO_EMAIL,  
            'token'                     => $PAGSEGURO_TOKEN,
            'creditCardToken'           => $creditCardToken,
            'senderHash'                => $senderHash,
            'receiverEmail'             => $PAGSEGURO_EMAIL,
            'paymentMode'               => 'default', 
            'paymentMethod'             => 'creditCard', 
            'currency'                  => 'BRL',
            // 'extraAmount'               => '1.00',

            'itemId1'                   => '0001',
            'itemDescription1'          => 'PHP Test',  
            'itemAmount1'               => $numero,  
            'itemQuantity1'             => 1,

            'itemId2'                   => '0002',
            'itemDescription2'          => 'PHP Test2',  
            'itemAmount2'               => $numero,  
            'itemQuantity2'             => 1,

            'reference'                 => 'REF1234',


            'senderName'                => $senderName,
            'senderCPF'                 => $senderCPF,
            'senderAreaCode'            => 83,
            'senderPhone'               => $senderPhone,
            'senderEmail'               => $senderEmail,
            'shippingAddressStreet'     => $shippingAddressStreet,
            'shippingAddressNumber'     => $shippingAddressNumber,
            'shippingAddressDistrict'   => $shippingAddressDistrict,
            'shippingAddressPostalCode' => $shippingAddressPostalCode,
            'shippingAddressCity'       => $shippingAddressCity,
            'shippingAddressState'      => $shippingAddressState,
            'shippingAddressCountry'    => 'BRA',
            'shippingType'              => 1,
            'shippingCost'              => $shippingCost,
            'installmentQuantity'       => 1,
            'installmentValue'          => $installmentValue,
            'creditCardHolderName'      => 'Chuck Norris',
            'creditCardHolderCPF'       => '54793120652',
            'creditCardHolderBirthDate' => '01/01/1990',
            'creditCardHolderAreaCode'  => 83,
            'creditCardHolderPhone'     => '999999999',
            'billingAddressStreet'     => 'Address',
            'billingAddressNumber'     => '1234',
            'billingAddressDistrict'   => 'Bairro',
            'billingAddressPostalCode' => '58075000',
            'billingAddressCity'       => 'João Pessoa',
            'billingAddressState'      => 'PB',
            'billingAddressCountry'    => 'BRA'
        );
```

Como eu faço para o PHP pegar **dinamicamente os itens do carrinho** e colocar dentro do array **$params[]**? Para que possa ser enviados todos os produtos do carrinho?

Essa parte pega os produtos para ser gerado dentro do array pelo PHP:

```
            'itemId1'                   => '0001',
            'itemDescription1'          => 'PHP Test',  
            'itemAmount1'               => $numero,  
            'itemQuantity1'             => 1,

            'itemId2'                   => '0002',
            'itemDescription2'          => 'PHP Test2',  
            'itemAmount2'               => $numero,  
            'itemQuantity2'             => 1,
```

Ficaria assim?

```
$params = array(



        'email'                     => $PAGSEGURO_EMAIL,  
        'token'                     => $PAGSEGURO_TOKEN,
        'creditCardToken'           => $creditCardToken,
        'senderHash'                => $senderHash,
        'receiverEmail'             => $PAGSEGURO_EMAIL,
        'paymentMode'               => 'default', 
        'paymentMethod'             => 'creditCard', 
        'currency'                  => 'BRL',
        // 'extraAmount'               => '1.00',

        'reference'                 => 'REF1234',    

        'senderName'                => $senderName,
        'senderCPF'                 => $senderCPF,
        'senderAreaCode'            => 83,
        'senderPhone'               => $senderPhone,
        'senderEmail'               => $senderEmail,
        'shippingAddressStreet'     => $shippingAddressStreet,
        'shippingAddressNumber'     => $shippingAddressNumber,
        'shippingAddressDistrict'   => $shippingAddressDistrict,
        'shippingAddressPostalCode' => $shippingAddressPostalCode,
        'shippingAddressCity'       => $shippingAddressCity,
        'shippingAddressState'      => $shippingAddressState,
        'shippingAddressCountry'    => 'BRA',
        'shippingType'              => 1,
        'shippingCost'              => '1.00',
        'installmentQuantity'       => 1,
        'installmentValue'          => '3.00',
        'creditCardHolderName'      => 'Chuck Norris',
        'creditCardHolderCPF'       => '54793120652',
        'creditCardHolderBirthDate' => '01/01/1990',
        'creditCardHolderAreaCode'  => 83,
        'creditCardHolderPhone'     => '999999999',
        'billingAddressStreet'     => 'Address',
        'billingAddressNumber'     => '1234',
        'billingAddressDistrict'   => 'Bairro',
        'billingAddressPostalCode' => '58075000',
        'billingAddressCity'       => 'João Pessoa',
        'billingAddressState'      => 'PB',
        'billingAddressCountry'    => 'BRA'
    );


$filter = preg_grep('/^itemId([0-9]{1,})/', array_keys( $params ));
    $result = array();
    for($i = 0; $i < count($filter); $i++)
    {

        $result['itemId' . ($i + 1)] = $params['itemId' . ($i + 1)];
        $result['itemDescription' . ($i + 1)] = $params['itemDescription' . ($i + 1)];
        $result['itemAmount' . ($i + 1)] = $params['itemAmount' . ($i + 1)];
        $result['itemQuantity' . ($i + 1)] = $params['itemQuantity' . ($i + 1)];

    }


    $header = array('Content-Type' => 'application/json; charset=UTF-8;');
    $response = curlExec($PAGSEGURO_API_URL."/transactions", $params, $header);
    $json = json_decode(json_encode(simplexml_load_string($response)));
?>
```

Comment: ficaria assim o que? eu te respondi o que está na pergunta dá uma olhada?

Comment: eu fiz o que você perguntou que é pegar os itens do carrinho!

Comment: como eu poderia enviar os itens do carrinho para o pagseguro?

$header = array('Content-Type' => 'application/json; charset=UTF-8;');
    $response = curlExec($PAGSEGURO_API_URL."/transactions", $params, $header);
    $json = json_decode(json_encode(simplexml_load_string($response)));

Comment: E ai deu certo a solução.?

Comment: deu certo sim :)

Comment: Porque você não pontua as questões e aceita como resposta, no seu usuário tem muitas perguntas em abertas! porque?

Comment: nao sei como faço isso, pode me dizer?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65143/discussion-between-virgilio-novic-and-wagner-martins-bodyboard).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para buscar campos específicos precisa primeiro descobrir quantos itens possui esse `array` que caracterizam a parte da chaves, por exemplo, o código verifica primeiramente com [preg_grep](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php) quantos itens possui a chave `itemId` independente da numeração, e com essa quantidade de `itemId` repetidos faz um `for` pela quantidade e gera um novo `array` com os resultados, ***exemplo***:

```
<?php

    $params = array(
                'email'                     => $PAGSEGURO_EMAIL,  
                'token'                     => $PAGSEGURO_TOKEN,
                'creditCardToken'           => $creditCardToken,
                'senderHash'                => $senderHash,
                'receiverEmail'             => $PAGSEGURO_EMAIL,
                'paymentMode'               => 'default', 
                'paymentMethod'             => 'creditCard', 
                'currency'                  => 'BRL',
                'extraAmount'               => '1.00',

                'itemId1'                   => '0001',
                'itemDescription1'          => 'PHP Test',  
                'itemAmount1'               => $numero,  
                'itemQuantity1'             => 1,

                'itemId2'                   => '0002',
                'itemDescription2'          => 'PHP Test2',  
                'itemAmount2'               => $numero,  
                'itemQuantity2'             => 1
    );

    $filter = preg_grep('/^itemId([0-9]{1,})/', array_keys( $params ));
    $result = array();
    for($i = 0; $i < count($filter); $i++)
    {

        $result['itemId' . ($i + 1)] = $params['itemId' . ($i + 1)];
        $result['itemDescription' . ($i + 1)] = $params['itemDescription' . ($i + 1)];
        $result['itemAmount' . ($i + 1)] = $params['itemAmount' . ($i + 1)];
        $result['itemQuantity' . ($i + 1)] = $params['itemQuantity' . ($i + 1)];

    }

    var_dump($result);
```

[***Exemplo OnLine***](https://ideone.com/8Aa0WZ)

<sub>***Referencias***</sub>

- [PHP preg-grep](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php)
- [How to search in an array with preg_match? - SO<sup>En</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8627334/how-to-search-in-an-array-with-preg-match)

Comment: editei minha pergunta, olha se fiz certo por favor